# Display a pulldown item in Eclipse programatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I know that I can declare actions in plugin.xml that specify style="pulldown" in order to make a pulldown style toolbar button, but I want to be able to do it programatically, using the `IToolBarManager` and `IContributionItem` interfaces.

I've looked through the interfaces, and the implementations of various things in eclipse, but I can't see how I'd do it. Ideally I want to add such a toolbar item from an `IEditorActionBarContributor` implementation.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, you need to create an `Action` object, and then call `setMenuCreator` on the action. Then when you add the action to the toolbar you'll get a drop down menu.